# How can I do 3D position tracking on an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, computer-vision

I'd like to move my iphone in space for a "3D Painting" style app so need to be able to capture its XYZ movement in space.  I wonder if there is some library that exists for this that does sensor fusion on the camera + gyro/accelerometer/magnetometer sensors.

I know there's OpenCV but that doesn't use the sensors as well to correct.

Comment: I don't know about any library. Do you know this paper? http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~mobile/Papers/2015ISMAR_ondruska.pdf

There is also an app called 123DCatch by Autodesk.

Comment: Hi @Anand, did you find what you're looking for?